# Adding bootstrap to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, railstutorial.org

I try to add bootstrap but it doesn't work!
http://hkar.ru/BMMZ

Comment: add
gem 'bootstrap-sass',   '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails'. '4.0.3'
and it works)

Comment: try using `gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git', :branch => 'next'`

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages into your question rather than forcing people to click on a link to look at a hard to read image of the error.  Also, please post a more detailed complaint than "it doesn't work." How does it not work? What is the exact issue? When requesting assistance, it's good form to make it easier to help you, rather than more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using `bootstrap-sass`. It most likely is a problem with that gem's dependencies. You need to include `sass-rails`.

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

This should solve it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work. This is exactly what the book says.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to include bootstrap with rails**

1) Add Bootstrap gem in Gemfile

**gem 'bootstrap-sass'**

**gem 'sass-rails'**

2) **bundle install**

3)Add bootstrap css to assets

Rename *application.css* in *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css* to *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass*
  then you can import bootstrap assets

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

4)Add bootstrap javascript to assets

Go to *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

> //= require bootstrap-sprockets

```
/*Use this after the jquery require in this file*/
```

This steps work fine for me.